# the conditions radio button to another page after submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm making an application with PHP and javascript

There are 2 choices Yes and No.

When he chose NO option and submits, then going to the page "Thank You" and its data into the database. When selecting the YES option it will go to another page and its data into the database

```
<label class="radio inline"><input type="radio" name="choose" id="optionsRadios1" value="Yes">YES</label>
<label class="radio inline"><input type="radio" name="usia" id="optionsRadios2" value="No">NO</label>
<label class="control-label" for="">Nama</label>
<div class="controls"><input type="text" name="nama" ></div><input type="submit" name="submit" value="" class="btn next">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
function submitPage(url){
    window.location.href=url;
}
$('input:radio').on('click',function(){
   var url=this.value=='Yes' ? 'xyz.php' : 'abc.php';
   submitPage(url); // or you can use ajax for post
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a javascript function and fire it on the onclick event of the radiobutton passing the radio value in the parameter

And then in the function put condition for redirect and form submit

or you can call a ajax to insert data in the database